# Determing when to use data structure approaches in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm going through Vue.js v2 documentation right now, and feel like I am running into a conflict in how data is structured.  [In official documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html) they use the following to create data:

```
var data = { a: 1 }
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: data
})
```

But while watching a video on [Vue JS Crash Course 2019](https://youtu.be/Wy9q22isx3U)  the speaker uses the following approach:

```
  export default {
    name: "app",
    data() {
      return {
        data: data
      }
    }
  }
```

- Are both these approaches valid as of today for Vue.js in 2019? If so, when do we use them in what environments?
- Also, why is it with the second example, I can't assign it to a specific element ID, like in the first example?
- There is a lot of talk in the documentation about using `new Vue` but I have not seen this used wi thin an `export default` tutorial.  Can this be done? for the purpose of using javascript to manipluate objects?  for example:

  ```
    new Vue({
      data: {
        a: 1
      },
      created: function () {
        // `this` points to the vm instance
        console.log('a is: ' + this.a)
      }
    })
    // => "a is: 1"
  ```

Thanks for walking through this with me so I get an overall understanding on when to use either approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You use `new Vue()` in JavaScript files and `export default {…}` in Vue files, with the `.vue` extension. A build tool will convert the Vue file to JavaScript and the code converted to Vue components.
2. The Vue single component file is generally used, but you can use the `Vue()` syntax if you don't want to use build tools.
3. In a Vue file, you're creating a single component. If you want to do manipulations, you should do it inside the component, there's no need to assign the component to a variable.
4. You can use `new Vue()` and Vue files together, but I think it's better to stick to one way of thinking. I recommend using Vue files with the `export default {…}` syntax.